# Why is sending data to local server using wamp unsuccessful?

Tags: php, html, mysql

```html
<form role="form" action="" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="form-username">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" class="form-username form-control" id="form-username" required="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="form-username">Middle Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="middlename" placeholder="Middle Name" class="form-username form-control" id="form-username">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="form-username">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-username form-control" id="form-username" required="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="form-username">Address:</label>
    <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address" class="form-username form-control" id="form-username" required="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="form-username">Phone No:</label>
    <input type="text" name="phoneno" placeholder="Phone No" class="form-username form-control" id="form-username" required="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="form-username">Email Id:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Id" class="form-username form-control" id="form-username" required="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="form-username">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-username form-control" id="form-username" required="">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn">Sign in!</button>
</form>
```

```html
<?php include_once('config.php');
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];    
    $middlename = $_POST['middlename'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $address =$_POST['address'];
    $phoneno = $_POST['phoneno'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
                    
    //query
    $query ="INSERT INTO login(`id`, `first_name`, `middle_name`, `last_name`, `address`, `phone_no`, `email`, `password`) VALUES ('',$firstname','$middlename','$lastname','$address','$phoneno','$email','$password')";                            
                   
    $result = @mysqli_query($query,$link);
    if (!$result) {
    echo "Data is not Inserted";     //this statement show me all time when submitting the data
    }else { echo "Data is Inserted Successful";}}?>
```

```
Can u help me what mistake i m doing.
```

Comment: when i enter all the details the click submit button it show me that data is not inserted. I try my best but i not understand what is the problem. please help me

Comment: The action attribute of the form tag needs to name the script it will pass the data to.

Comment: check `id` value in sql statement. can you try by assigning a value (number)  to `id` in sql statement?

Comment: If it shows "data not inserted", then the script is being executed. The form's action is not a problem. The problem is somewhere in the php part.

Comment: This would also be an opportune time to make the obligatory "use prepared statements" comment. As long as you're having a problem with the database access, use this opportunity to learn how to use placeholders in the query.

Comment: I just noticed the @ sign in mysqli_query.. this is hiding any error notifications that would help you debug the problem. Get rid of that, and post what you find.

Comment: Enable error messages.

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things you can do:

- Remove @ in front of `myslqi_query` to show the error message.
- If you still see no error message, then make sure that errors will get reported. See [display-errors](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) and [error_reporting()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).
- Do `echo $query` right after it is defined. If the query looks right, then copy it, and try running it against your database, using a MySQL client, such as HeidiSQL, or `mysql` command line.
- Correct your english. Do not use "SMS english". It will encourage people to help you.